# Mounted device showing in df and /etc/mtab but missing from /proc/mounts and /proc/self/mounts. Why?

Tags: mount, df, device, proc

I have an ec2 instance that is booted from an ebs snapshot. The boot device is `/dev/sda1`. When I call `mount`, `df -h` or `cat /etc/fstab` I can see the device:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw)

$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              50G   20G   28G  43% /

$ cat /etc/mtab
/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw 0 0
```

But when I `cat /proc/mounts` and `cat /proc/self/mounts` `/dev/sda1` is missing. Why would this be?

This isn't causing me a problem, and the instance is running fine, it just means I can't use a [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) update, because that's checking for mounted filesystems via `/proc/self/mounts` and complains that `/dev/sda1` is missing (when it obviously isn't), and I'd like to understand why.

Comment: [`/proc/mounts`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) should be a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`  and maybe you are running with namespaces ( as root: `lsns -l`) ; then  a process will only see the mount points that are present in that namespace, which may omit others ....

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the symlink, but it's an older Debian with no namespaces support.

Comment: I've worked around my monit issue by instead of monitoring `/dev/sda1` (which is missing from `/proc/self/mounts`) to monitor `rootfs` (which does appear in `/proc/self/mounts`) aka `/` aka `/dev/sda1`